# BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED: and revalidation of the purchase

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-billing

If the purchase in the app calls `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED`: 
need to call the

> acknowledgePurchase(...

function to revalidate the order?

Answer (score 3):

`acknowledgePurchase()` doesn't let to buy an item twice.

An item cannot be purchased twice, to be able to buy again it must be first consumed by calling `billingClient.consumeAsync()`

`acknowledgePurchase()` need to be called in a short time period after a successful purchase, that's if `billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK` and `purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED` Not doing it makes the purchase to be refunded.

A purchase may return `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED` if you try to buy again while validation is pending but don't call `acknowledgePurchase()` until it returns `billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK`and `purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED`